# Play framework reverse route expects Nothing as parameter in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using a reverse route that works on **Play Framework 2.3.10** but **IntelliJ IDEA 16** (latest version so far) points an error:

```
@helper.form(routes.MyController.doSomething(userEmail)) {
    ...
}
```

IDEA expects a parameter of `Nothing`, so this change "removes" the IDEA error (but it won't work, obviously, since the parameter is a `String`).

```
@helper.form(routes.MyController.doSomething(new Nothing)) {
    ...
}
```

By the way, methods without arguments don't have that issue:

```
@helper.form(routes.MyController.doWhatever()) {
    ...
}
```

The controller is like:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    public Result doSomething(String email) {
        ...
    }

    public Result doWhatever() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Do you know how to remove the error in IntelliJ IDEA?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are having very similar issues to me as you can see here:

[Intellij Play Intellisense issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438148/intellij-play-intellisense-issues/36439242#36439242)

For me the code will compile but intellij's "intellisense" is thinking the parameters aren't correct, even though they are.