# Intellij Play Intellisense issues

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

[image: showing the issue]

I am having issues with intellij intellisense sometimes where the code compiles fine and works, but intellij is showing that the code is invalid.

In this particular case the error is saying the following:

```
Cannot resolve method 'javascriptRouter(java.lang.String,
 play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute,
 play.core.Router.javascriptReverseRoute)
```

Is this a bug in intellij, or do I need to adjust some of my settings?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jetbrains is aware of the issue and are looking into fixing it.  Here is the link to the issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FSCL-9930

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal, it's not a bug in IntelliJ.

IntelliSense is going to give you possible methods, but if you plug in mismatched parameters it's not going to compile.

If you want to know for sure, double-click on the method name and type {Ctrl-B} and it'll go to the definition of the method and you should be able to see what the method parameters are (and there could be multiple methods with slightly different signatures).

Comment: Well if you read the question you would clearly see that it doesn't produce a compile error and that the website runs just fine, so it is indeed that intellij specifically is reporting a red squiggle line under a function that clearly isn't causing an error when compiling, even when using intellij to compile.  It may not be a bug, but it definitely is specific to intellij.